# rsync --perms - what difference does it make

Tags: linux, osx, rsync

I am on MacOS and the --perms flag doesn't appear documented when I use `rsync -h`..what difference does the `rsync --perms` flag make? Supposedly it preserves file permissions but why wouldn't rsync do that by default?

Answer (score 2):

The `rsync -h` option is a summary, not the full authoritative documentation.

I was able to find more detail by running `man -P 'less -p --perms$' rsync` on my MacOS's default rsync. `rsync --perms` copies the source permissions to the destination permissions as you posited.

From the manual:

> In summary: to give destination files (both old and new) the source permissions, use --perms. To  give  new  files  the  destination-default  permissions  (while  leaving  existing  files unchanged),  make  sure that the --perms option is off and use --chmod=ugo=rwX (which ensures that all non-masked bits get enabled).

A user might simply not want to copy the source file's permissions to the destination file. For example, if copying a local configuration file to a remote server, the remote might have a different set of permissions.

The above use case is supported by `rsync`'s `--chmod`. Other `rsync` options like `--executability` and `--no-perms` suggest yet more use cases in which we can't assume every user/use case expects destination files to match the source.

The difference is that `--perms` forces the source permissions to the destination, while default behavior (no `--perms`) is dependent on the umask or setgid of the directories and/or processes in question.

From slightly further down the same manual entry:

> When this option is off, permissions are set as follows:
>
> - Existing  files  (including  updated files) retain their existing permissions, though the ‑‑executability option might change just the execute permission for the file.
> - New files get their "normal" permission bits set to the source file's permissions masked with the receiving end's umask setting, and their special permission  bits disabled except in the case where a new directory inherits a setgid bit from its parent directory.